# Jmeter - How to extract value from the request (not response) using RegEx

Tags: jmeter

I have JSON request as following:

```
{
    "type": "SIGNUP",
    "data": {
        "userAccountInfo": {
            "email": "ta0620050706@gmail.com",
            "password": "qweQwe123!"
        },
        "userAddressInfo": {
            "country": "United States"
        },
        "userPersonalInfo": {
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test"
        }
    }
}
```

How can extract ta0620050706@gmail.com from the following request, considering the value of the email is always dinamic?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and the above JSON is in the "Body Data" tab like:

[image]

You can extract the email by adding a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and using the following code there:

```
vars.put('email', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()).data.userAccountInfo.email)
```

It will extract the value you're looking for and store it into `${email}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)